# Install Snow Lepard from USB

Tags: snow-leopard, usb, startup, ssd

I have a clean and formatted SSD where I want to install Snow Leopard from a USB flash drive containing a OS X image from a (not the one it came with) original install-DVD. But for some reason it wont boot from the USB. I though this was the way to do it? When I created the image I chose "compressed" format. Maybe that's the reason?

What to do?

Comment: If not the one it came with, which installation DVD? Installation media bundled with the computer might only install on the model they came with.

Comment: @Gerry   
My friends DVD. My own install DVD was corruped. But how am I suppose to get OS X installed if my USB is bundled as well? Sounds retarted :) But im dont think thats the issue. Because when I turn on the macbook, it cant find the flash drive. The big "?" is just flashing. Holding alt/option or C doesnt work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have because Snow Lepoard doesnt work with USB booting. I tried with a torrent downloaded Lion and that worked along with "Lion Diskmaker" (Just google it).